# Datepicker Icon only works with id tag, not class tag

Tags: jquery-ui, class, datepicker, icons

I am trying to get the Datepicker Calendar Icon to appear next to the input textbox. However, using 'id=datepicker' I can only get it to appear next to the Departure Date's textbox, but not next to the Return Date's textbox. This is because I am using 'id' twice, however when I switch it to 'class=datepicker' the Icon disappears from both.

```
<html>

...

<head>

...

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });
  });
  </script>

...

</head>


<body>

...

<strong>Departure date</strong><span>*</span>:
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="departuredate"/>

<strong>Return date</strong><span>*</span>: 
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="returndate"/>

...
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });
      $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });    
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not:

1. Include the same JavaScript (either minified or not) multiple times in the one page.
2. Assign the same ID to multiple elements in the one page.

If you do the following (note the different IDs):

```
<strong>Departure date</strong><span>*</span>:
<input type="text" id="dDatepicker" class="datepicker" name="departuredate"/>
<strong>Return date</strong><span>*</span>: 
<input type="text" id="rDatepicker" class="datepicker" name="returndate"/>
```

Then this will work:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
  });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/fS4cY/1/).

**Edit**

You may also need to check your CSS, as the datepicker class may be overridden. Maybe try including onlynone jquery-ui.css to test.

If it is just a case of the calendar icon not rendering, then you need to specify the correct path to the calendar.gif file. So say you can see the file in your browser when you go to `http://mysite.com/path/to/images/calendar.gif`

You then need to set up datepicker like so:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/path/to/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I see what you did, however as soon as I assign datepicker to 'class' the icon disappears from both boxes.

Comment: No, but thanks for all your help. I managed to get around the error by using the code in the answer below this one. Thanks again.